# Switching $2\int_0^{2\pi} |\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})|d\theta$ to $4\int_0^{\pi} \cos(\frac{\theta}{2})d\theta$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Context:** Obtaining the arclength of path $r=\cos(\theta)+1$ (polar) using a path integral, $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$.

I'm currently following a solution guide to a problem, and at one step, the author switches from $2\int_0^{2\pi} \left|\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|d\theta$ to $4\int_0^{\pi} \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)d\theta$.

This is probably a really obvious/dumb question but why does he do this? I notice that you get two completely different results depending on whether or not you make this step. But why is it done?

Comment: I would take that step just to get rid of the absolute value.

Comment: You should get the same result either way because they are in fact equal. You can see it by the symmetry in the graph. The part of the graph over $[\pi,2\pi]$ is just a shift over of the part over $[0,2\pi]$, thanks to the $|\cdot|$ which strips the sign.

Comment: I meant "...flip over of the part over $[0,\pi]$". Can't edit the comment for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first like to point out that the result should be the same regardless of whether you take the step to change the integral. See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*Integrate%5BAbs%5BCos%5Bx%2F2%5D%5D%2Cx%2C0%2C2Pi%5D) and [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4*Integrate%5BCos%5Bx%2F2%5D%2Cx%2C0%2CPi%5D), which yield the same result.

Now, take a look at the graph of $\displaystyle f_1 (x) = \cos \frac{x}{2}$

[image]

Letting $\displaystyle f_2 (x) = |f_1 (x)|$, we get

[image]

And notice how $f_2 (x)$ is symmetric along the line $x = \pi$. Because $\displaystyle |\cos \frac{\theta}{2}|$ is the only term in the integrand, we note that we can split the integral into two parts, namely:

$$2 \int_0^{2\pi} |\cos \frac{\theta}{2}| d\theta = 2 \int_0^{\pi} \cos \frac{\theta}{2} d\theta + 2 \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \cos \left(\pi - \frac{\theta}{2}\right) d\theta = 4 \int_0^{\pi} \cos \frac{\theta}{2} d\theta$$

Picture credits go to Wolfram Alpha.